# Debugging Flask app - How can I find out what caused a 400 bad request error?

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn, foreman, bad-request

I am currently developing my first Heroku python flask web app and I am testing it locally with gunicorn and foreman. I keep getting 400 bad request responses when I try to make GET requests with json encoded in the url arguments. However, I can't figure out what is going wrong. The server log doesn't print anything. No errors are logged and there aren't any messages about having received a request either.

What can I do to get more information about what is going wrong? Do I need to configure one of these tools to log errors in more detail? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

(`app.debug = True` by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know for sure if this is what was causing my problem, but I realized that the JSON I was passing as a URL argument was quite long (about 8000 characters before URL encoding). Another SO question suggests that typical limits are around 2000 characters. I've resolved my issue for now by using a POST request instead, but I would still love to know how to get more verbose debugging information from the web app if anyone has any tips.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Blueprints? In my experience, Blueprints keeps any output from showing up in the console. Here's a simple logging function that I use to get around this is:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(format="[%(asctime)s]  %(levelname)s:%(message)s")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def logging_fun(method, remote_addr):
    log.info('HTTP %s request from %s' % (method, remote_addr))

@blueprint.route('/servers', methods=['GET'])
def list_servers():
    """Gives a list of all registered servers."""
    logging_fun(request.method, request.remote_addr)
```

You could also have it iterate through and print `request.args` if you need to see if the URL arguments are there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I am not using Blueprints. It is also worth noting that the function bound to my url, `list_servers` in your example, never seems to get called in my web app.